# Are questions about the Armory game engine on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Armory](http://armory3d.org/) works only within Blender, however it is a separate product. There is a version that is an add-on, presumably that's on topic. Then the full version is a separate product, but you can't use it unless you run Blender, it works only within Blender.

So, are questions about it on topic?

Comment: I'd say *yes*; it's not all that different from an addon for an alternate render engine (for example). That said, it's a tricky question right now since it isn't totally freely available yet. I'll also note that there has been a project similarly developed "in" blender ([microvellum](https://www.blendernation.com/2014/01/24/interior-design-and-architectural-rendering-with-microvellum-and-blender/)), but I don't believe questions about it are on topic.

Comment: Honestly with the bge being basically dead now I don't see why not as well once it's fully open source.

Answer (score 6):

Sure! Armory questions are on topic.
However, I can not guarantee that you will get answers. (But that should not stop you from trying, everything started somewhere.)

We already take blend4web questions. I'd argue this is more closely related to blender then b4w.